# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError in quicksort program

Tags: java, data-structures, quicksort

```
public class QuickSort {

    static void Sort( int[] arr, int low, int high ) {
        if (low >= high) return;
        int mid = low + (low - high) / 2;
        int pivot = arr[mid];
        int i = low;
        int j = high;

        while (i < j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (arr[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;

            }
        }
        if (low < j)
            Sort(arr, low, j);
        if (high > i)
            Sort(arr, i, high);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int[] arr = {5, 8, 45, 3, 54, 8, 3, 5, 31, 4, 21, 2, 5, 1}; //hardcode

        System.out.print("Before  quick sorting:");

        for (int j : arr) {
            System.out.print(" " + j); //loop for printing array
        }

        System.out.println(); // print statement for printing it on nextline;
        Sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

        System.out.print("After quick sorting:");

        for (int j : arr) {
            System.out.print(" " + j);////loop for printing array
        }

    }
}
```

this is the java program written for the implementation of quick sort algorithm i've used java 8 to implement this algo but i am not able to figure out what is causing this in fact on net there is so many implementation but mine is the easy way to understand i request to all programmer help me out to resolve my problem  where m getting error on my recursive if statement please help me out m stuck on this

this is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at QucikSort.Sort(QucikSort.java:21)
    at QucikSort.Sort(QucikSort.java:21)
```

Comment: Is that your homework?

Comment: Hard to tell just by looking at it, but looks to me like you don't have a case for low == high

Comment: Problem is with your pivot index. Take `low+(high-low)/2;`